# How to Ignore a Folder when using watch with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, webpack-watch

I have the following function:

```
export default function(path, urlKey = 'static') {

    if (urlKey === 'static') {
        path = require(`~/static${path}`).default;
    }

    urlKey = Object.keys(config.app.urls).includes(urlKey) ? urlKey : 'static';

    return (config.app.urls[urlKey] + '/' + path).replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1");

};
```

As you can see, I am using a dynamic `require` which I believe utilises `require.context`. When my webpack bundles, it builds all the files in the static folder. The `~/static` part of the path is an alias to my `static` folder in the root directory.

When using the `watch` mode of webpack, the bundling goes into an endless loop.

I have tried various things such as `watchOptions.ignored` and the [`WatchIgnorePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/watch-ignore-plugin/) but neither of these have worked.

These are my two attempts with the above solutions:

```
watchOptions: {
    ignored: /static/
}
```

and

```
plugins:[
    new WatchIgnorePlugin([
        path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static')
    ]),
]
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing here?

Comment: Why have you tagged webpack 2 and 4? Surely you're using one or the other, not both.

Comment: you couldn't be more helpful hahaha))

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally. Watch mode does not "loop endlessly". You'll need to provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been experiencing the issue of endless rebuilds. After many tries, I was finally able to exclude the **static** folder by using the *WatchIgnorePlugin* in my *webpack.dev.config.js*:

```
devWebpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../static')
    ])
```